# Синтаксический разбор по схеме: проверка

Tags: синтаксис

День был так хорош,солнце так ярко; а эта тоненькая и хорошенькая девушка не знала и не хотела знать про его существование и была довольна и счастлива какой-то своей отдельной,верно глупой,но веселой и счастливой жизнью.сложное предложение усложненной структуры,провести синтактический разбор по схеме:1)определить количество предикативных частей в составе усложненной конструкции,пронумеровать каждую часть 2)указать какие виды связи в нем представлены (однотипная связь или разнотипная связь,какие именно) 3)определить уровни членения если есть 4)назвать,на какие блоки делиться предложение на первом уровне членения(если есть) 5)указать вид связи между блоками и смысловые отношения между ними 6)объяснить постановку знака препинания между блоками 7)определить синтаксическую структуру каждого блока (если блоки в свою очередь еще членятся на блоки ,то назвать эти блоки на втором уровне членения ,указать вид связи между этими блоками и указать смысловые отношения между ними. 8)членить блоки на составляющие их предикативные единицы, определить характер связи предикативных частей и смысловые отношения между ними 9)объяснить постановку знаков препинания  между предикативными частями 10)составить графическую схему предложения. Спасибо тем кто сможет помочь!!!

Comment: А Вы не можете или просто лень? Форум не выполняет д/з.

Answer (score 1):

(День был так хорош 1),(солнце так ярко 2); (а эта тоненькая и хорошенькая девушка не знала и не хотела знать про его существование и была довольна и счастлива какой-то своей отдельной,верно глупой,но веселой и счастливой жизнью 3).
 Связи-бессоюзная + сочинительная

1 уровень -два блока, соед. сочинит. связью со знач противопоставления.

Точка с запятой разделяет предл. на 2 части, разные по смыслу.

2 уровень-в 1 блоке 2 предикат. основы, связанные бессоюзной связью и перечислит. интонацией, поэтому простые предложения разделяются запятыми.

[- =],[- =];а [О и О - = и = и = и = О,О, но О и О].